# What is the correct string gauge for an Alvarez LJ2E acoustic guitar?

Tags: guitar, strings, string-gauge

I am going to change the strings on this guitar for the first time. A google search brings up one website that says that it uses 13-56 strings, but this is not mentioned on the official Alvarez website, and I want to make sure I get the string gauge correct.

Edit: Apologies for the poorly worded question. I specifically wanted to know the string gauge that Alvarez ships this model with, not what is "correct".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no correct gauge - for any guitar. There is a manufacturer's recommended gauge, but most players will have their own favourite gauge - I have for 50 odd years - based on playability, tone, volume, and other personal factors.

Since you have already been playing this guitar, are you totally satisfied, or are there chaanges you'd like to make? Maybe change the top three for lightre gauge, a plain third, a thicker bottom string?If you're totally satisfied, go to the string shop, get them measured, or do like I do, use a gauge to check: (Vernier, caliper). Or contact Alvarez...

Comment: I'm concerned that the intonation will go off if I use a string gauge that's different from the one that came with the guitar.

Comment: That's a fair comment. Although going up or down a couple of thou won't make *that* much difference. If you do change the gauge, it's worth the trouble to find just how much it goes out. On the lower frets there won't be so much change that it becomes unplayable. I changed to.008s on an old (50year old) Epiphone acoustic years ago, and it's been fine all that time.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Tim, that sounds encouraging :) it's easy to get paranoid reading about guitar on the internet.

Comment: I got a reply from a Parts and Service Manager at Alvarez. This guitar ships with D'Addario EXP16 strings, a light gauge set .012 through .053. Your answer was very helpful but I will set mine to the "accepted answer" since it directly answers the question. Thanks Tim!

Comment: Due to an edit in the question, this answer doesn't supply exactly what OP asks for, however, it stays as is!

Answer (score 0):

Got a reply from a Parts and Service Manager at Alvarez. This guitar ships with D'Addario EXP16 strings, a light gauge set .012 through .053. Hope this is useful for someone else!

Comment: To be honest, this answer is only useful to owners of Alvarez LJ2E guitars - maybe one in 50,000 readers - or less?

Comment: This question is also only useful to owners of that guitar, so that seems appropriate given the scope? If this site is not a good place for model-specific questions, I will make a note of that.

Comment: As Tim mentioned, despite them shipping the guitar with that set, it doesn't mean it is the correct set. The correct set depends much more on the player than the guitar.